# Redirect page when user is verified

Tags: php, html, session, verify

i have this code to verify if users have Administrator account to backoffice of my website, but if user don't have it don't redirect user to `..index.php`. He stay in this page but no content is shown.

Code of verification

```
<?php
$Usuario = isset($_SESSION["Usuario"]) ? $_SESSION["Usuario"]: '';
$Rank    = isset($_SESSION['Rank'])    ? $_SESSION['Rank']   : '';

if ($Usuario != '' && $Rank == 'Administrador'){  
} 
else 
{
    echo "<script>alert(\"Area Restrita\");</scrpit>";
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
?>
```

In this page, (header) i call this file to verify session.

```
<?php
session_start(); 
require_once "../config.php";
require "verificar.php";

?>

<div id="header">
        <a href="index_logged.php?page=index"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "but if user don't have it (access) don't redirect user to ..index.php"

Comment: If user is Member, he don't redirect user to ../index.php. Only Administrator can acess this page.

Comment: Why u do a PHP redirect AND a JS redirect? The PHP will suffice. Also add an ´exit;` after the `header('Location: ....');` (for good practice). U'll get a warning if u output that `script` tags before the header location : `Warning: Headers already sent at ...` making the PHP redirect not to work proper

Answer (score 0):

Your index file:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
require_once "../config.php";
require "verificar.php";

?>

<div id="header">
        <a href="index_logged.php?page=index"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
</div>
```

Your verification file:

```
<?php
$Usuario = isset($_SESSION["Usuario"]) ? $_SESSION["Usuario"]: '';
$Rank    = isset($_SESSION['Rank'])    ? $_SESSION['Rank']   : '';

if ($Usuario != '' && $Rank == 'Administrador'){  
    // do some action for administrator
} 
else 
{
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit();
    //echo "<script>alert(\"Area Restrita\");</scrpit>"; <-- you don't need this here
}
?>
```

Note, that I commented echo. You mustn't output anything before `header`. If you will output something (and you do in your example) you will get `headers already sent` error.

Your main mistake is you output something first and after that tried to redirect.

Anyway, I think better to use a bit another approach.

Form and form handler:

```
<?
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // here is some query which will check if this user with this password exists and get the role of the user
    // if exists $userExists = true; else $userExists = false;
    if($userExists) {
        $_SESSION['userLoggedIn'] = true;
        if($role == 'administrator') {
            $_SESSION['isAdministrator'] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['isAdministrator'] = false;
        }
        header('Location: index.php');
            exit(); // <-- don't forget this
    }
    else
    {
        // handler for bad user/password
    }
?>

<form action='' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='username' />
    <input type='password' name='password' />
</form>
```

Now, pages which are restricted will start from this code:

```
<?
    $isAdministrator = $_SESSION['isAdministrator'];
    if(!$isAdministrator) {
        ban_ban_ban();
        die('bye bye');
    }

    // content for administrator
?>
```

**NOTE: This is just example, don't forget to add some check everywhere!!!!!11**

But, as you wish :) Hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

`header("Location: ../index.php");` is not going to stop the rest of the code from running - if you just want to redirect him you should `die();` or `exit;` right after you send the `Location` header

The `alert` part before the `Location` header is also unnecessary because the browser will redirect the user before he'll be able to see the alert. and also it is forbidden to call `header` function after you sent something to the output (for example, like you did with `echo`)

Another thing that you should consider - is the security issues that raised from validating user solely by looking at values in the `$_SESSION` - this means - that if someone is logged - you are not able to log him out until the session expires

The better way is to keep some token in the `$_SESSION` and save the status of the user in the database - that way, you can change his status directly from the DB without relying on the session/changing code